# Removing glow from behind and around trees

Tags: lightroom, photoshop, editing

I've been editing a landscape image with lightning in the sky, and I've brought up the clarity and contrast in Lightroom to make it stand out more.  However, I end up with a noticeably brighter sky around trees on the horizon, as well as in between branches and such in the trees.  Most of the methods I've found online have messed up because of the trees on the horizon.

How can I make the sky on the horizon and behind the trees blend in?

Comment: Do you have an example image you can upload for us to work with?

Comment: @Hueco The effect is fairly common when using heavy local contrast in a photo with very dark and very bright areas right next to each other.

Comment: @MichaelClark true, I just think that questions involving post are better examples when images can be provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The halos are caused by increasing local contrast globally (over the entire image at once) when the image has fairly dark and fairly bright areas that are next to one another.

There's no extremely easy way to deal with it. The most common way is to use layers and create separate masks for the dark and light areas and apply the localized contrast (that's what the clarity slider does) separately to each area.

Comment: I went back and remade the mask I used for local contrast/clarity and made it feathered to the edge of the trees.  I was able to get the look I wanted without the halo.