# Halo in pictures taken with HDR

Tags: hdr, pentax

I have a [Pentax K-S2](https://www.ricoh-imaging.co.jp/english/products/k-s2/) and whenever I use the A-HDR  (advanced HDR) mode, the pictures come out with this strange halo around the edges of objects. Is this normal?

[image: sample 1].

[image: sample 2]

Comment: Related: [How to avoid these artifacts around cables in HDR?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/103209/15871) and [Removing glow from behind and around trees](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/101341/15871). There are quite a number of other existing questions/answers that show up if you search the site for "halo".

Answer (score 9):

Is it normal?  Yes… and no.

It depends on the ability/quality of the HDR routine and its ability to recognise & correctly handle edges where the overall light level changes rapidly.

A low-ability algorithm will leave this halo to a greater or lesser extent - it's pretty much the trademark of poor HDR. This is an area where modern phones are beating regular cameras hands-down. They can form very well-defined masks to separate these contrast edges & the results are getting close to invisible.

For a DSLR etc, the best way to do this is actually in post, in Photoshop or a dedicated HDR app such as Aurora HDR [which I just learned is discontinued - the functionality has now been folded into [Luminar Neo]](https://skylum.com/luminar)

Some examples [chosen not by its inspiring subject matter but just because I rarely take photos that include sky;)… The processing was done on a small jpg not the original file, to make the results worse.

<sup>Click for full size</sup>
Original
[image]

Photoshop, with the borders set intentionally high and overall settings to emphasise the bad edges. Clear halo. [Photoshop can do a lot better than this, but is not as good as dedicated software]
[image]

Aurora, at default settings, very slight halo
[image]

Aurora with intentionally aggressive settings, reasonably acceptable halo for the settings
[image]

AI-based algorithms will tend to improve on these results as they are developed further. My versions of Photoshop & Aurora are pre-AI. Newer software is likely to be better still.

Answer (score 2):

The Halo effect you are seeing is the result of Unsharp masking (USM) imo. It seems likely your camera's A-HDR mode runs the photo through a faily intense USM. Many devices try to emulate HDR images using post-processing filters like this, however as you can see the results often have noticable drawbacks.

On a side note:
If you want the highest dynamic range you're better off getting your cameras exposure and white-balance well adjusted for the scene and editing the RAW image manually.

Comment: No, these artifacts have nothing to do with USM.

Comment: @jarnbjo many HDR are generated using various Tone-Mapping algos which are very closely related to Unsharp Masking, in fact some do just run a large-radius unsharp mask.